# Convert my API result into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, api, httr, jsonlite

I am really struggling to understand how this newly released API works.. Can someone please help me turn it into a useful dataframe in R? My `res` looks like the below (edited):

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

#GET Function

res = GET("https://comtradeapi.un.org/data/v1/get/C/A/HS?reporterCode=826&period=2020&partnerCode=000&partner2Code=000&cmdCode=TOTAL&flowCode=M HTTP/1.1&subscription-key=6509aa2a08d54ca7b47a2fece2ab5bee")

df= fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content)) #this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

By pasting your URL into a browser we get:

{"elapsedTime":"0.02 secs","count":0,"data":[],"error":""}

So there appears to be an error with the result itself. Also, **I'd strongly advise against publishing your secret API key, as it allows others to access the data you're subscribing to!**

Comment: The following returns your error in R:

`txturl <- url("https://comtradeapi.un.org/data/v1/get/C/A/HS?reporterCode=826&period=2020&partnerCode=000&partner2Code=000&cmdCode=Total&flowCode=M&customsCode=C01&motCode=1000&aggregateBy=cmdCode&breakdownMode=plus&includeDesc=true&subscription-key=6509aa2a08d54ca7b47a2fece2ab5bee")

txt <- readLines(txturl, warn=FALSE)

result <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(txt)`

Comment: +1 for the advice on the API key.  Having done it, it is now compromised, even if you edit your post.  Therefore, do whatever you need to do to delete that key and get a new one

Comment: Hello do you mean the result has an error or the API call has an error? I tried another call here which seems to be correctly written: ```response = GET("https://comtradeapi.un.org/data/v1/get/C/A/HS?reporterCode=826&period=2020&partnerCode=000&partner2Code=000&cmdCode=TOTAL&flowCode=M HTTP/1.1&subscription-key=6509aa2a08d54ca7b47a2fece2ab5bee")```

Comment: No worries on the token it is a free registration. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Is an HTTP API call the same one used by R or is this unsupported? I'm afraid I don't understand the format of the request and the data retrieved and I can't troubleshoot it myself.

Comment: I'd be careful about assuming that a response received in a browser is the same as the one received by `httr::GET()`. Although in this case it seems to be, a server may look at headers before deciding what response to send.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the API key. Indeed I can regenerate a new one. However as I currently cannot access the data anyway this point is somewhat woot.